# No provider for MatDialogRef

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I am using material 2 version 2.0.0-beta.12. I need to adjust the position of the material Modal. I followed this answer to do that. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44238699/8253445 Since `MdDialog` is not available now I used `{MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA}`.

```js
constructor(public dialog: MatDialog,public dialModRef:MatDialogRef<any>) {}
```

When I add MatDialogRef to my constructor it gives me the error:

> No provider for MatDialogRef

### dialog-overview-example.ts

```js
import {Component, Inject} from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from
'@angular/material';

@Component({
    selector: 'dialog-overview-example',
    templateUrl: 'dialog-overview-example.html'
})
export class DialogOverviewExample {

    animal: string;
    name: string;

    constructor(public dialog: MatDialog,public
    dialModRef:MatDialogRef<any>) {}

    openDialog(): void {
        let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
        width: '500px',
        data: { name: this.name, animal: this.animal }
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
        console.log('The dialog was closed');
        this.animal = result;
    });
    }
}

@Component({
    selector: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog',
    templateUrl: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog.html',
})
export class DialogOverviewExampleDialog {

constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }

    onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
    }
}
```

### app.module.ts

```js
entryComponents: [DialogOverviewExample,DialogOverviewExampleDialog]
```

### dialog-overview-example-dialog.html

```html
<h1 md-dialog-title>Hi {{data.name}}</h1>
<div md-dialog-content>
    <p>What's your favorite animal?</p>
    <md-form-field>
    <input mdInput tabindex="1" [(ngModel)]="data.animal">
    </md-form-field>
</div>
<div md-dialog-actions>
    <button md-button tabindex="2">Ok</button>
    <button md-button (click)="onNoClick()" tabindex="-1">No Thanks</button>
</div>
```

Comment: instead of `any`, give the name of the Component class you want to open in dialog. Then, add the component class in your entryComponents.

Comment: I did that now..I still get the same error :(

Answer (score 46):

You will get that exact

> No provider for `MatDialogRef`

error in case you include your dialog's component html selector in `dialog-overview-example.html` like `<dialog-overview-example-dialog></dialog-overview-example-dialog>`

There is no need for that, do not include the html selector of the dialog component anywhere.

Comment: Thanks Javier, this was killing me and your answer fixed it

Comment: Thanks Javier, I really hate that aspect of angular. It's like the errors are intentionally vague

Comment: Thanks Javier. This fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 38):

You need to import this module in your module file (`app.module.ts` by default):

```
import { MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
```

and add `MatDialogModule` to `imports` in your module declaration:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [
    ...
    MatDialogModule,
    ...
  ],
  providers: [...],
  entryComponents: [...],
  bootstrap: [...]
})
```

**EDIT:**

You need to pass data through `this.dialogRef.close();` to get `result` in `subscribe` working. For example:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog',
   templateUrl: 'dialog-overview-example-dialog.html',
})
export class DialogOverviewExampleDialog {
someValue: boolean = false;

constructor(
  public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DialogOverviewExampleDialog>,
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { }

 onNoClick(): void {
   this.dialogRef.close(this.someValue);
 }

}
```

Comment: I imported the module and the dialog is working when I remove MatDialogRef from the constructor..I wanna know why it stops working when I import that :(

Comment: @kashifroshen have you added your components (where you import `MatDialogRef`) to `entryComponents` in module declaration?

Comment: Yeah I did that as well :/ :/

Comment: I found the solution..instead of giving it to the DialogOverviewExample constructor it should be given to the DialogOverviewExampleDialog constructor..the error is gone now..I am calling the changePosition inside that class but still the position is not getting updated for some reason.

Comment: @kashifroshen how do you call `changePosition`? Do you use `this.dialogRef.close(...)`?

Comment: I called it inside the constructor..and yes I am using that..you can see that at the end of the code snippet of dialog-overview-example.ts I have included in the question.

Comment: would that help in altering the position of the modal?

Comment: @kashifroshen in your code you have `this.animal = result`, but without passing data through `this.dialogRef.close(...);`, `result` will be null. What functionality will modal have? Is it some kind of animal chooser with buttons for animals? Post .html template for this component please.

Comment: added it :) it is just the example modal in the provided in the material 2 site..i want to get it centered in the page..but it is on the far left side

Comment: If it's on the left side, you probably have custom css that modify it - default css for modal keeps it centered.

Comment: I didn't apply any styles for the component :/ plus I checked it from the browser..there was no style to pin it to the left though

Comment: I have the same issue, but I imported MatDialogModule. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 15):

### Update 2021

The Angular bug that caused the error `No provider for MatDialogRef` when importing from `@angular/material/dialog` has been fixed.

The correct way to import `MatDialogRef` is once again to use the specific component entry point:

```js
import {MatDialog} from '@angular/material/dialog';
```

### Angular Material Module

```js
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';

@NgModule({
  exports: [
    MatDialogModule,
    ...
  ]
})
export class MyMaterialModule {}
```

#### Original Answer September 2019

Many of the [Angular Material examples](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples) show the `MatDialogRef` import as:

```
import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog';
```

<del>This will cause the following **error** (for example, when creating a Service to wrap the creation of Dialog Components):</del>

```
ERROR NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[DialogComponent -> MatDialogRef]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[DialogWarningComponent -> MatDialogRef]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialogRef!
```

### <del>Correct Import: '@angular/material'</del>

<del>import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material';</del>

Comment: I was breaking my head for the error source. The point "Correct Import: '@angular/material'" worked for me. Thanks mate.

Comment: Components can no longer be imported through "@angular/material". Use the individual secondary entry-points, such as @angular/material/button.

Answer (score 9):

You injected `MatDialogRef` in the constructor of `DialogOverviewExample` component that opens your dialog, but it is not a dialog.

`MatDialogRef` can be inject only in components opened as dialog, other way there is no `dialogRef` so this error is triggered.

Comment: Good point, I had the same problem when doing a refactor and moved the logic responsible for opening a dialog from a component to a service, so I simply copied the dialogRef into the service constructor, which is a copy-paste mistake. Moving the dialogRef outside of the service constructor fixed the issue.

Answer (score 6):

The issue is that you are including your `<dialog-component></dialog-component>` in your code somewhere as well as injecting it into your view with @Inject. If you remove your `<dialog-component></dialog-component>` from whichever template.html you had it in, It will work!

Answer (score 3):

Remove MatDialogRef from DialogOverviewExample component. You don't need it there. It should work then.

Answer (score 2):

I faced to that issue in **2023** in application which is based on **Angular 15**.

The change of an import path solved problem. Try this:

```
import { MatLegacyDialogRef as MatDialogRef, MAT_LEGACY_DIALOG_DATA as MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/legacy-dialog';
```

then `constructor` stays the same:

```
  constructor(
    public myDialogRef: MatDialogRef<UserDialogComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public modalData: any
  ) {}
```

Hope this helps.