# MatDialog position relative to triggering element

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, positioning, android-relativelayout

I have a matdialog which I'm trying to position relative to the element that is triggering it.

**mainComponent.ts**

```
openDialog() {
const element = document.getElementById('btn');
const myDialog = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent, {
  width: '500px',
  height: '500px',
  data: {
    something,
    something: something
  },
  position: { top: `${element.top + 5}px`, right: `${element.right + 5}px` }
});
```

Unfortunately this does not position the dialog close to my triggering element, it just tosses it randomly on the webpage.

Also, I don't have a Dialog Service and don't intend to create one.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Many thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a Stackblitz demo please?

Answer (score 2):

Dialogs aren't designed to be opened relatively to an element. [Overlay](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview) will better suit you as it supports various [Position](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview#position-strategies) and [Scroll](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview#scroll-strategies) strategies. In your case you can use a [FlexibleConnectedPositionStrategy](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/api#FlexibleConnectedPositionStrategy), like:

```js
const positionStrategy = this.overlay.position()
    .flexibleConnectedTo(someElement)
    .withDefaultOffsetX(10);

this.overlayRef = this.overlay.create({
    positionStrategy: positionStrategy
});

...
```

Comment: According to this post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58757670/angular-material-how-to-position-matdialog-relative-to-element) it seems that it can be. But the only difference is that I don't want to use a service.

Comment: @blk In your example a custom dialog component is used which positions itself according to an element which is passed to it. It isn't a natural way of using dialogs, it's like a hack. It's better to use an overlay, which is designed for such use cases.

Answer (score 1):

use getBoundingClientRect

```
const element=document.getElementById('btn');
const rect=element?element.getBoundingClientRect():{top:0,left:0}
const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogOverviewExampleDialog, {
  width: '250px',
  data: {name: this.name, animal: this.animal},
  position:{top:(rect.top+5)+'px',left:(rect.left+5)+'px'}
});
```

NOTE, you can pass too a reference variable and use

```
<button #bt mat-raised-button (click)="openDialog(bt)">Pick one</button>

//and 
openDialog(bt:any): void {
  const element=bt._elementRef.nativeElement
  const rect=element?element.getBoundingClientRect():{top:0,left:0}
  ...
}
```

see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-12ab2o?file=src/app/dialog-overview-example.html)

Comment: This was my first attempt at it but it doesn't work because I have some zoom effects which changes the viewport.

Comment: I think you can multiply by a factor, but really I dont' know