# mat dialog to open only in active component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

in landing component i have 2 components side by side.

say ComponentA, ComponentB

if i open mat -dialog from Component A, mat dialog should overlay in component A only not in parent component, Please help

Forgot Password?

```
ForgotPassword(){
    console.log("open")
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ForgotPasswordDialogComponent, dialogConfig);
  }
```

Comment: Please add more details

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular Material: How to position MatDialog relative to element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58757670/angular-material-how-to-position-matdialog-relative-to-element)